# CSS display auto leaves blank space at top

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position

I have a div with `style="position:relative;height:300px;overflow:auto;width:100%;"` it works perfectly in chrome and firefox. If I try in Internet explorer, there is some blank space above the div in which I apply that style. But only in Compatibility mode. In other modes it works perfectly.

If I change position value to absolute, it does not leaves blank space. But the height of the parent div is set to auto which does not resize when giving absolute.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any other elements inside the parent `div`? Is the white space the same height as one of those other elements? I'd need more HTML to help you here.

Comment: The elements contain a table in the following structure |image|text|text| when i checked the offset value, top offset was larger than i expected. I even tried to set the top to 0. It didn't work..

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of the issue? There is probably a margin that isn't collapsing somewhere.

Comment: sorry.. even jsfiddle does not seem to work in IE10 Compatibility view